# Getting Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate is valid for ingress.local, not rancher

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, rancher, rke

As part of renewing our cluster certificate we have accidentally deleted our "tls-rancher-ingress secret" from local cluster, after that we are unable to access cluster through kubectl and getting error like "Getting Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate is valid for ingress.local, not rancher",please guide us if there is any way to add the secret again without using kubectl?

Comment: Try using `kubectl ... --insecure-skip-tls-verify`. And let me know it this solves it

Comment: Thankyou, we resolved this issue after adding decoded certificate to kubeconfig

Comment: Can you post the steps you have followed to resolve the issue as an answer and accept it.